# Haskell grouping list elements by fst

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a function

```
group::[(Int, Int)]->[[(Int, Int)]]
```

that would group elements of a list of tuples into subgroups dependant on the first coordinate, ie:

```
group [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

should result in

```
[[(1,1),(1,2)],[(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]]
```

I'd imagine list comprehension is the way, but I'm a bit stuck.. Could someone provide an advice/solution?

PS the function could also take as an argument the maximum the first coordinate can take, if that would be of any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy)

```
λ: groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
[[(1,1),(1,2)],[(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]]
```

The [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) function is useful here to shorten the code a bit without obfuscating it:

```
λ: groupBy ((==) `on` fst) [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
[[(1,1),(1,2)],[(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for ```groupBy ((==) `on` fst) [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3)]```. Would you just sort before hand if you wanted to do this?

Comment: @tcotts Yes, in case you want to have _all_ tuples with the same first element be in one group (and not just runs of consecutive tuples), you'd sort first.